# Got error of "Too many open file", what's the ulimit when running the program using ProcessBuilder()...start()?

Tags: java, linux, ulimit

I need to run a program after a Linux EC2 machine is provisioned on AWS. The following code will get "Too many open file" error. `my_program` will open a lot of files, maybe around 5000.

```
string cmd = "my_program";
Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
                      .inheritIO()
                      .command(cmd)
                      .start();
```

However, running `my_program` in the console can finish without any error. What's the `ulimit` when running the program using ProcessBuilder()...start()?

`ulimit -n` output 65535 in bash terminal.

Comment: Please add output of `ulimit -n` to your question (no comment).

Comment: The value of a `ulimit` doesn't depend on Java.  It is something that is set outside of your Java program.  And your Java program can't change it. So, the answer to your question is "We can't tell you, but you can find it out for yourself using the `ulimit` command".

Comment: Why do you need to open all those files _at the same time_?

Comment: @Cyrus `ulimit -n` returns 65535 in terminal.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- it runs a pyspark script. The Spark code `spark.read.oprtion(...).parquet(*files)` opens a lot of files.

Comment: I suggest that your real problem may be a file descriptor leak.

Comment: @user207421, the python code is actually pyspark code. How to tell if it's a file descriptor leak?

Answer (score 0):

First find out the limits your app has when running:

```
ps -ef | grep <<YOUR-APP-NAME>>
```

then:

```
cat /proc/<<PID-of-your-APP>>/limits
```

Here the problem is that you app. starts under X or Y user and these users have a different ulimit setup.

Check:

```
cat /etc/security/limits
```

... I think and increase those values.

Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you `close()` the files after use.  They will be closed by the garbage collector (I'm not completely sure about this, as it can differ on each implementation) but if you process many files without closing them, you can run out of file descriptors right before the garbage collector has any chance to execute.

Another thing you can do is to use a resource based `try` statement, that will ensure that every resource you declare in the parenthesis group is a `Closeable` resource that will be forcibly `close()`d on exit from the `try`.

Anyway, if you want to rise the value of the maximum number of open files per process, just look at your shell's man page (bash(1) most probably) and search in it about the `ulimit` command (there's no `ulimit` manual page as it is an internal command to the shell, the `ulimit` values are per process, so you cannot start a process to make your process change it's maximum limits)

Beware that linux distributions (well, the most common linux distributions) don't have normally a way to configure an enforced value for this in a *per user* way (there's a full set of options to do things like this in BSD systems, but linux's `login(8)` program has not implemented the `/etc/login.conf` feature to do this)  and rising arbitrarily this value can be a security problem in your system if it runs as a multiuser system.